# Upload file from flutter to server NodeJS using multer in node

Tags: node.js, flutter, multer

I'm using flutter for frontend of an mobile application and nodeJS for backend , i'm trying to upload photo using multer , in backend it works perfectly and i tested it with postman but when i got problem when i send file from flutter .

Flutter Code

```
    Future<void> getImage() async {
        final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    
        setState(() {
          if (pickedFile != null) {
            _image = File(pickedFile.path);
          } else {
            print('No image selected.');
          }
        });
      }
    upload(File imageFile) async {
    var stream =new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(imageFile.openRead()));
    var length = await imageFile.length();
    var uri = Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.8:8081/products/add-product");
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
    var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('photo', stream, length,filename: basename(imageFile.path));
    request.files.add(multipartFile);
    var response = await request.send();
  }

 

   if(_image.path != null){
           upload(_image);
          _addProduct(context, product);
                            }
```

part of Code node post

```
 router.post('/add-product', upload.single('photo'),async (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.file);
    const product = new Product({
        name : req.body.name,
        price : req.body.price,
        detail : req.body.detail,
        quantity : req.body.quantity,
        photo : req.file.path 
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can send a byte array much easier with no problems or any additional packages.

Just make additional arguments that can take an int array or an unint8List or, even better, you can use base64 encoding and send it as a String. After picking the file, just use readAsBytes and send it with your request body. Or encode the unit8list into base64 and then send it. It will be simple from the Flutter app side, but your going to handle it on the server side using a base64 decoder and saving the file.